# How to return a dictionary of values from loss function in Jax?

Tags: python, logging, jax

Suppose you have a loss function and you want to track various sub-components of the loss while you train. What is that most "jax" way to do this?

```
def loss(params, x, y):
    ...
    loss_1 = ...
    loss_2 = ...
    loss = loss_1 + 0.1 * loss_2
    return dict(loss=loss, loss_1=loss_1, loss_2=loss_2)


@jax.jit
def update(params, tau, y):
    f_value, grads = jax.value_and_grad(loss)(params, tau, y)
    # something like this
```

Are you suppose to just use `grad` on a function pulling the loss out and then recalc the values again? Is there no way to do this hwith `value_and_grad` more efficiently?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your question is. Can you give an example of what you'd like to calculate?

Comment: @jakevdp I am just trying to minimize the loss in a standard jax loop. A pattern I would typically use in tensorflow 2.0 is to return a bunch of debug information from the loss ... I think maybe the "jax" way of doing this is as an array and not a dict. When I revalue the function at debug iterations it slows things down quite a lot

Comment: To be more concrete... in your code snippet, what do you want `f_value` and `grads` to contain? As written, it results in an error, because `grad` implements reverse-mode autodiff for a function that returns a scalar, and your function does not return a scalar.

Comment: @jakevdp Yes that is my question, how to avoid the error. In tf I think you get around this by not calling helpers that try to do everything for you. You call the function (get all the values) but compute the gradient w.r.t. the one thing you want. Is the only way to do this to *re* call the function after the gradient is obtained? Is there some way to get side information while training? There must be a jax pattern for this.

Comment: @jakevdp So for example, I need to compute loss_1 and loss_2 and their sum each time to compute the loss. I need the gradient of the sum to optimize. Every 100 (or whatever) steps I might like to save the values of loss_1, loss_2, etc for debugging. Maybe calling the loss function again is not the worst but it seemed to be quite slow.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want `grads` to be a dictionary with keys `loss`, `loss1`, `loss2` and values containing the gradient of each result with respect to the input?

Comment: @jakevdp yes. I can use a list. I am really asking what is the patter people use with jax to return or log side information from the loss calculation. I'm open to doing it however people do it. I haven't seen the pattern yet.

Comment: @jakevdp Hmmm maybe it is this. https://github.com/google/jax/pull/484 just saw it now after a deeper google.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to none other than @jakevdp himself for prompting me to think of some alternative google queries and it turns out that as of https://github.com/google/jax/pull/484 there is an aux option to the grad function. I think this is not immediately obvious to tensorflow 2 users migrating to jax just because of the way you use GradientTape explicitly.

Something like the example below shows auxilary information returned. It even seems to handle a dict which is useful for periodically logging inside the update loop.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
theta = jax.random.normal(key, (10, 1))
y = np.random.randn(10, 1)
alpha = 0.01

def loss(theta, y):
    loss_reg = jnp.sum(theta ** 2)
    loss_data = jnp.sum((y - theta) ** 2)
    loss = loss_data + alpha * loss_reg
    return loss, dict(loss_reg=loss_reg, loss_data=loss_data)

grad, aux = jax.grad(loss, has_aux=True)(theta, y)

display(grad)
display(aux)

try:
    jax.grad(loss)(theta, y)
except TypeError as e:
    print(f'yes got error {e}')
```

Output:

```
DeviceArray([[-1.4899637 ],
             [-0.71481365],
             [-0.6030376 ],
             [-0.8263864 ],
             [-1.8103108 ],
             [ 0.69435316],
             [-1.5611547 ],
             [-1.6380725 ],
             [ 0.9838154 ],
             [ 0.21186407]], dtype=float32)
{'loss_data': DeviceArray(3.3714797, dtype=float32),
 'loss_reg': DeviceArray(2.658556, dtype=float32)}
yes got error Gradient only defined for scalar-output functions. Output was (DeviceArray(3.3980653, dtype=float32), {'loss_data': DeviceArray(3.3714797, dtype=float32), 'loss_reg': DeviceArray(2.658556, dtype=float32)}).
```

Comment: This answer was useful to me. Thanks.