# GPU allocation explodes when logging scalar to flax's tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorboard, jax, flax

I noticed that when I use flax's tensorboard `from flax.metrics import tensorboard` to log the loss, the GPU allocation explodes.

To compute the loss metrics I use the `has_aux` as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154040/how-to-return-a-dictionary-of-values-from-loss-function-in-jax).

These are the functions I am using. In the model class:

```py
@partial(jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def compute_losses(self, params, x_train, y_train) -> dict:
    # data fit loss
    y_pred = self.forward(params, x_train)
    rec_loss =  jnp.mean(jnp.abs(y_pred - y_train)**2)
    # reguralizations
    # ...
    loss_dict = {"rec":rec_loss}
    return loss, loss_dict
    
@partial(jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def grad_loss(self, params, x_rec, y_rec):
    return jax.grad(self.compute_losses, has_aux=True)(params, x_rec, y_rec)
```

In the main:

```
grads, loss_dict = model.grad_loss(params, input, target)
updates, opt_state = optimizer.update(grads, opt_state)
params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)
# log loss
if step % config.logging.log_every_steps == 0 and config.logging.log_loss:
    # compute loss
    loss_dict = model.losses_no_grad(params, input, target)
    for term in loss_dict.keys():
        writer.scalar(f'loss/{term}', loss_dict[term], step)
```

Without the writer, the GPU consumption is around 25%. If activated, it goes up to 100%. Why is it happening?

EDIT:
This does not happen with `from torch.utils import tensorboard`.
You can see the GPU consumption [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4D6Kjv2lmkwkiNS_ALQXwN76pOcLQ2_/view?usp=drive_link)